# Virtual Reality: How to move camera with user's physical motion in Unity3D

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I am trying to move a camera in the virtual environment, when I move while holding my mobile device. So far I can search on the internet and there is no much help I found. I am using Unity 5.2.4.

If someone has done the work of a similar type?

Thanks.

Comment: You could use the accelerometer but keep in mind that moving in VR will bring nausea to many users. In the case of acceleration, you could read the value and apply them to the camera based on rotation. Also, your user won't see and that makes it dangerous to move around, what if using near a cliff. You'd be better off using checkpoints like old arcade gun games.

Comment: While dangerous idea, still interesting. Depends - if you want to move only indoors and small distances - use accelerometer - your only choice here. If you want to move outside and longer distances - look for GPS/map data + accelerometer.

Comment: Do you put your camera as a object's child?

Comment: Yes, but I have to move the object using mouse and/or keyboard. But I need to move it when I move in the x and z plane. I am not talking about changing the angles, I am talking about moving the object as I move.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of self-content positional tracking for mobile VR is not easy to solve and that's why there is no solution on Google Cardboard and GearVR SDKs, at least for a while. Also keep in mind that there is no good approach that uses only the IMU data.

The approaches investigated by the time uses a variety of computer vision techniques, using sensor fusion and the mobile camera like the one presented by Univrses, or using depth cameras like the StructureSensor.

John Carmack from Oculus is also working on a solution to achieve a good positional tracking for GearVR (https://youtu.be/dRPn_LK2Hkc).

More about the complexity evolved in this problem [here](http://venturebeat.com/2016/02/24/why-positional-tracking-for-mobile-virtual-reality-is-so-damn-hard/).